# Non-Relativistic theories of light

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light

Why can light be easily described using non-relativistic theories, since it moves at maximum speed (ie it can not be more relativistic than it already is)?

Comment: Like which non-relativistic theory?

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my comment, classically light is described by Maxwell's equations, in a vacuum

$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}=0 \\
\nabla \times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\\
\nabla \times\mathbf{B}=-\mu_0\left(\mathbf{J} + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\right)    $$

These equations can be manipulated to obtain the two wave equations

$$\square\mathbf{E}=0\\
\square\mathbf{B}=0 $$

where $\square=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2 $. These wave equations are the classical description of light, the solutions are waves traveling at speed $c$ where the electric and magnetic fields are orthogonal to each other.

Consider a Galilean boost $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow\mathbf{x'}=\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{v}t$ which corresponds to shifting into a reference frame moving at velocity $\mathbf{v}$ in galilean relativity. Now, we should fine the same equation in the new reference frame, but surprise, we don't, because

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t'}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla$$

Thus $\square'\neq\square$ and these equations are not invariant under a Galilean transformation! At this point physicists were asking the question: is Maxwell's theory wrong or is Galilean relativity wrong? Einstein correctly argued that the latter was the right option and developed special relativity. As a matter of fact, if you ask the question "which kind of transformation of the coordinates leave Maxwell's equations invariant?" and do the calculation, you will get exactly the Lorentz transformations.

So not only the classical theory of light is fundamentally relativistic, it is what made physicists realize that there was a need for a new theory of relativity!

Comment: so to answer the question: you get a non-relativistic theory of light by using Maxwell's Equation, but only in one stationary reference frame.

Comment: @JEB I don't think it makes sense to state that a theory is relativistic or not if you just stay in one reference frame, by relativistic I mean Lorentz invariant, what do you mean?